# Service Provider ComponenetSpace Identity Provider ADFS 2.0 Issue in in enabling SSO for .Net Application

Tags: single-sign-on, claims-based-identity, saml-2.0, adfs2.0, federated-identity

I am enabling SSO for an existing .net application. I am using componentspace SAML 2.0 component as service provider(SP) and ADFS 2.0 as identity provider(IdP) i have configured ADFS on different service and SP is on different server.I am launching SP InitiateSSO is called and browser get redirected to IdP url and based on the relay party url its returned back to SP.

When trying to get:

```
SAMLServiceProvider.ReceiveSSO(Request, out isInResponseTo, out partnerIdP, out userName, out attributes, out targetUrl);
```

its saying "The partner identity provider http://sp.com/adfs/services/trust is not configured".

in fiddler I am getting following calls.

- /login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fDefault.aspx
- /adfs/ls/?SAMLRequest=7b0HYBxJliUmL23Ke39K9UrX4HShCIBgEyTYkEAQ7MGIzeaS7B1pRyMpqyqBymVWZV1mFkDM7Z28995777333nvvvfe6O51OJ%2Fff%2Fz9cZmQBbPbOStrJniGAqsgfP358Hz8iHjfZolw9Ol638%2BWr%2FBet86ZNz55%2B9tHvf%2F5gOr032d3bPp%2Fszbb3Z5%2FubR9MHxxs7%2BUP9mezncn93cnso%2FQn87opquVnH%2B2Ndz5Kz5pmnZ8tmzZbtvTRzu697R1648GbnQeP9u892r0%2F3n9w8FMfpU%2Bpl2KZtfzmvG1Xj%2B7eLZZtnc2KfDGeVou72ey8uVs2dz9Kn1X1NGf0PvvoPCubHN28zJqmuMztJy%2Frqq2mVfmkWM6K5cVnH63r5aMqa4rm0TJb5M2jdvro9fEXzx8Rmo8m0qh59O03b15uv%2Fzy9ZuP0uOmyWvgc1Itm%2FUir1%2Fn9WUxzb969VwwbAjFWb6oxiGeAHp36OVx1qzefZS%2BW5TL5hHTeTNiKx3FR0c8K4%2BYnLX3%2FubXM4PGR0fDGD%2B%2B64E%2B0tl%2FQbDOnr6symJ6DYIvsna4q93xLn9SzLbPuemj9bJZ5dPivMiJI47Lsro6qfOspelp6zXNzt0j6TVks6P%2FBw%3D%3D&SigAlg=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F09%2Fxmldsig%23rsa-sha1&Signature=rXOfg3K3D87RobofnuU5xXfBbYYIlHOeNf3IkOrLVekTycKWW7foBAKeBuatyyaCZwnmZMWJiMOGU87P4NOy0YXGdO3F5VhvZ9ZGLxK74GWrTOvWmvY%2Fa4z%2FrGRv6TkNRRMdy6rZS5sBn%2B1aQx0bzlPwAMwaCVbIU%2FQxTJa4zok%3D
- /adfs/ls/auth/integrated/?SAMLRequest=7b0HYBxJliUmL23Ke39K9UrX4HShCIBgEyTYkEAQ7MGIzeaS7B1pRyMpqyqBymVWZV1mFkDM7Z28995777333nvvvfe6O51OJ%2Fff%2Fz9cZmQBbPbOStrJniGAqsgfP358Hz8iHjfZolw9Ol638%2BWr%2FBet86ZNz55%2B9tHvf%2F5gOr032d3bPp%2Fszbb3Z5%2FubR9MHxxs7%2BUP9mezncn93cnso%2FQn87opquVnH%2B2Ndz5Kz5pmnZ8tmzZbtvTRzu697R1648GbnQeP9u892r0%2F3n9w8FMfpU%2Bpl2KZtfzmvG1Xj%2B7eLZZtnc2KfDGeVou72ey8uVs2dz9Kn1X1NGf0PvvoPCubHN28zJqmuMztJy%2Frqq2mVfmkWM6K5cVnH63r5aMqa4rm0TJb5M2jdvro9fEXzx8Rmo8m0qh59O03b15uv%2Fzy9ZuP0uOmyWvgc1Itm%2FUir1%2Fn9WUxzb969VwwbAjFWb6oxiGeAHp36OVx1qzefZS%2BW5TL5hHTeTNiKx3FR0c8K4%2BYnLX3%2FubXM4PGR0fDGD%2B%2B64E%2B0tl%2FQbDOnr6symJ6DYIvsna4q93xLn9SzLbPuemj9bJZ5dPivMiJI47Lsro6qfOspelp6zXNzt0j6TVks6P%2FBw%3D%3D&SigAlg=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F09%2Fxmldsig%23rsa-sha1&Signature=rXOfg3K3D87RobofnuU5xXfBbYYIlHOeNf3IkOrLVekTycKWW7foBAKeBuatyyaCZwnmZMWJiMOGU87P4NOy0YXGdO3F5VhvZ9ZGLxK74GWrTOvWmvY%2Fa4z%2FrGRv6TkNRRMdy6rZS5sBn%2B1aQx0bzlPwAMwaCVbIU%2FQxTJa4zok%3D
- /SAML/AssertionConsumerService.aspx

Stack track

```
[SAMLException: The partner identity provider http:// sp.com/adfs/services/trust is not configured.]
  ComponentSpace.SAML2.Configuration.SAMLConfiguration.GetPartnerIdentityProvider(String name) in c:\Sandboxes\ComponentSpace\SAMLv20\Library\Configuration\SAMLConfiguration.cs:245
  ComponentSpace.SAML2.SAMLServiceProvider.ReceiveSSO(HttpRequest httpRequest, Boolean& isInResponseTo, String& partnerIdP, String& userName, SAMLAttribute[]& attributes, String& relayState) in c:\Sandboxes\ComponentSpace\SAMLv20\Library\SAMLServiceProvider.cs:664
  ComponentSpace.SAML2.SAMLServiceProvider.ReceiveSSO(HttpRequest httpRequest, Boolean& isInResponseTo, String& partnerIdP, String& userName, IDictionary`2& attributes, String& relayState) in c:\Sandboxes\ComponentSpace\SAMLv20\Library\SAMLServiceProvider.cs:637
  ExampleServiceProvider.SAML.AssertionConsumerService.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Program Files (x86)\ComponentSpace SAML v2.0 for .NET\Examples\SSO\HighLevelAPI\WebForms\ExampleServiceProvider\SAML\AssertionConsumerService.aspx.cs:28
  System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +25
  System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +42
  System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +132
  System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +66
  System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2428
```

ADFS Configuration is:

```
<PartnerIdentityProvider Name="https://sp.com/adfs/services/trust"
   SignAuthnRequest="true"
   WantSAMLResponseSigned="false"
   WantAssertionSigned="false"
   WantAssertionEncrypted="false"
   UseEmbeddedCertificate="true"
   SingleSignOnServiceUrl="http://sp.com/adfs/ls/"/ >
```

Service provider configuration are as:

```
<SAMLConfiguration xmlns="urn:componentspace:SAML:2.0:configuration">
<ServiceProvider Name="https://demo.sp.com"
   AssertionConsumerServiceUrl="~/SAML/AssertionConsumerService.aspx"
   CertificateFile="sp.pfx"
   CertificatePassword="password" />
```

ERROR that i am getting in:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
The partner identity provider http:// sp.com/adfs/services/trust is not configured. Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: ComponentSpace.SAML2.Exceptions.SAMLException: The partner identity provider http:// sp.com/adfs/services/trust is not configured.
```

Answer (score 0):

I got that problem resolved by changing the order of authentication.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1600.ad-fs-2-0-how-to-change-the-local-authentication-type.aspx

Now its working. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The following error is actually thrown by ComponentSpace:

> The partner identity provider http://sp.com/adfs/services/trust is
>   not configured

This is because your `PartnerSP` key in `<appSettings />` and your `Name` attribute in `<PartnerIdentityProvider />` do not match:

**saml.config**:

```
<PartnerIdentityProvider Name="https://sp.com/adfs/services/trust" ... />
```

**Web.config**:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="PartnerSP" value="http://sp.com/adfs/services/trust />
    ...
</appSettings>
```

The Name of the PartnerIdentityProvider should be set to: `http://sp.com/adfs/services/trust`